# Setting up framework (OpenEars) in a non-Xcode iPhone project (MobileSubstrate tweak with Theos)

Tags: xcode, frameworks, makefile, tweak, openears

Here is the link to setting up the OpenEars framework in Xcode: http://www.politepix.com/openears/configuring

However, I'm making a tweak using Theos, so I need to configure it, manually I suppose, by editing the makefile made by Theos.
Could someone with more experience maybe explain how each of the steps on the page would carry over to my context.

Pretty much it says I need to add OpenEars as a target dependency, then link to libOpenEarsLibrary.a and AudioToolbox.framework and AVFoundation.framework and libiconv.2.4.0.dylib, add OpenEars/CMULibraries/flite-1.4-release/include and OpenEars/CMULibraries/pocketsphinx-0.6.1/include and OpenEars/CMULibraries/sphinxbase-0.6.1/include and OpenEars/OpenEarsLibrary/Classes/include to my header search path, and lastly set "Compile for thumb" to no.
I could do these things in Xcode, but I'm not editing an Xcode project here, I've just got a Theos project with a makefile. So what do I do?